# Need my 2d array to print but it only shows one point in the output box

Tags: java

I'm doing my online course for grade 12 programming and we are using java applications in net beans. We need to create a program that displayed an inputed students 4 test grades up to 15 students.

I've set it up so the array like this

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String testOne = test1Input.getText();
    String testTwo = test2Input.getText();
    String testThree = test3Input.getText();
    String testFour = test4Input.getText();
    String studentNames = (firstInput.getText() + " " + secondInput.getText());

    students[next][0] = studentNames;
    students[next][1] = testOne;
    students[next][2] = testTwo;
    students[next][3] = testThree;
    students[next][4] = testFour;
    next++;
}
```

when I go to display it using

```
private void listButoonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    for (int row = 0; row <= 15; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= 4; col++) {
            outBox.setText(students[row][col] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

it only shows the third test mark

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package studentGrades;

/**
 *
 * @author stuba
 */
public class UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public static String[][] students = new String[15][4];
public static int next = 0;

/**
 * Creates new form UI
 */
public UI() {
    initComponents();

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    title = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    firstLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    secondLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    firstInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    secondInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    test1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    test2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    test3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    test4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    test1Input = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    test2Input = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    test3Input = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    test4Input = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    addButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    listButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    stundentAvButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    courseAvButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    exit = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    outBox = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));

    title.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    title.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    title.setText("Student Grades");

    firstLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    firstLabel.setText("First Name:");

    secondLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    secondLabel.setText("Last Name:");

    firstInput.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

    secondInput.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

    test1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    test1.setText("Test 1");

    test2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    test2.setText("Test 2");

    test3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    test3.setText("Test 3");

    test4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    test4.setText("Test 4");

    test1Input.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

    test2Input.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

    test3Input.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

    test4Input.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

    addButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    addButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    addButton.setText("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    listButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    listButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    listButton.setText("List");
    listButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            listButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    stundentAvButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    stundentAvButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    stundentAvButton.setText("Student Average");

    courseAvButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    courseAvButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    courseAvButton.setText("Course Average");

    exit.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    exit.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 204));
    exit.setText("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(outBox);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(test3)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(firstLabel)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(firstInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(test1)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(test1Input, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(18, 18, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(listButton)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(courseAvButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(addButton)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(stundentAvButton))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                            .addComponent(secondLabel)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(secondInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(title)
                    .addGap(99, 99, 99))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(test3Input, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(test2)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(test2Input, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(test4)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(test4Input, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)))
            .addGap(52, 52, 52))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(exit))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(title)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(firstLabel)
                .addComponent(secondLabel)
                .addComponent(firstInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(secondInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(test1)
                .addComponent(addButton)
                .addComponent(stundentAvButton)
                .addComponent(test1Input, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(test2)
                .addComponent(test2Input, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(test3)
                .addComponent(listButton)
                .addComponent(courseAvButton)
                .addComponent(test3Input, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(test4)
                        .addComponent(test4Input, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 103, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(exit))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

   String studentNames = (firstInput.getText() + secondInput.getText());

    students[next][0] = studentNames;
    students[next][1] = test1Input.getText();
    students[next][2] = test2Input.getText();
    students[next][3] = test3Input.getText();
    students[next][4] = test4Input.getText();
    next++;


}                                         

private void listButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int row = 0; row <= 15; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= 4; col++) {
            sb.append(students[row][col] + " ");
        }
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    outBox.setText(sb.toString());
}                                          

private void exitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    System.exit(0);
}                                    

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new UI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
private javax.swing.JButton courseAvButton;
private javax.swing.JButton exit;
private javax.swing.JTextField firstInput;
private javax.swing.JLabel firstLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JButton listButton;
private javax.swing.JTextPane outBox;
private javax.swing.JTextField secondInput;
private javax.swing.JLabel secondLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton stundentAvButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel test1;
private javax.swing.JTextField test1Input;
private javax.swing.JLabel test2;
private javax.swing.JTextField test2Input;
private javax.swing.JLabel test3;
private javax.swing.JTextField test3Input;
private javax.swing.JLabel test4;
private javax.swing.JTextField test4Input;
private javax.swing.JLabel title;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: What do you think `outBox.setText(students[row][col] + " ");` should do when called repeatedly? What makes you think so?

Comment: its to display all of the inputted students and their marks in the out box

Comment: Object of what *class* does `outBox` hold? When you visit documentation of that class what does it say about `setText` method?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post [mcve]. This will help you with "I need the help faster".

Comment: @Pshemo it is a JTextArea. the set text method is just to set the text in the box to whatever I specify

Comment: So what do you think should happen if JTextArea already contains some text, lets say "foo" and you call `setText("bar")`?

Comment: @c0der its in netbeans ide9.0 im not sure how to make it minimal and complete? im complete new to all this help stuff so I apologize

Comment: Minimal - without any unnecessary parts, Complete - so we could copy-paste it and without modification get same results/problems you are getting.

Comment: Side note : why `String testOne = test1Input.getText();` and `students[next][1] = testOne;`  and not `students[next][1] = test1Input.getText();` ?

Comment: I changed to what you said, I was just wonder for the minimal and comlete thing would it be too sketchy if I sent the .rar file of my program for netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

You keep overriding the text in the output box. One better approach is to accumulate the text in a `StringBuilder`, and only then set it to the output box:

```
private void listButoonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int row = 0; row <= 15; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= 4; col++) {
            sb.append(students[row][col]).append(" ");

        }
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    outBox.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: I've tried the string builder and nothing happened? Since its in netbeans id copy paste the thing but theres the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in there so im not sure. Would I be able to send the .rar file of my program to use?